# Does anyone know how to install linux on the Samsung Galaxy TabPro S?

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, live-usb, samsung

I would like to install Ubuntu on this Windows 10 2-in-1 device from Samsung. It has a UEFI BIOS system so it seems that it would be possible. I'm also new to UEFI BIOS, a simple description on how to do this would be great.

---

```
                                       Useful Info:
                           This device runs a x64 architecture OS
```